# Using php to loop through and split items into uneven divs

Tags: php, html

Looping through 12 items I would like to separate the whole list into divs so that 0,1 are in a div, 2 in a div, 3,4 in a div, 5 in a div and so on..

```
<!-- half half 0,1 -->
<div class="right-grid-row">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        0
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        1
    </div>
</div>

<!-- full 2 -->
<div class="right-grid-row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
        2
    </div>
</div>

<!-- half half 3,4 -->
<div class="right-grid-row">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        4
    </div>
</div>

<!-- full 5 -->
<div class="right-grid-row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
        5
    </div>
</div>
```

I assume modulus is needed on the multiple loops but I'm struggling a little bit.

Notes**

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++): ?>
        <?php echo $i; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the modulus operator, but here's another way you could do it:

```
$counter = 1;
for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
   ... // create inner div
   if ($counter == 2)
      echo '</div><div class="medium-12 columns">';
   else if ($counter == 3) {
      echo '</div><div class="right-grid-row">';
      $counter = 0; // reset the counter
   }
   $counter++;
}
```

It's simple and relatively easy to read. This code is not complete, you would need to handle your first opening opening and last closing divs, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++): ?>
                    <?php switch($i) { ?>
                      <?php case '0':  ?>
                      <?php case '1':  ?>
                      <?php case '3':  ?>
                      <?php case '4':  // add more if needed ?>
                      <?php      //your code ?>
                      <?php      break; ?>
                      <?php default: ?>
                      <?php      //your other code ?>
                    <?php } ?>
            <?php endfor; ?>
```